# How to send customParameters in twilio Voice sdk for javascript using nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I've got a problem, the additional data I want to send through outgoing and incoming call are not present, or is not being received.

the MyCustomField field should come to the other instance, (Where the call is answered) because it is a browser - to  - browser app, then. I want to receive my custom field, but it doesn't work. Thanks for take time and answer.

I have tried the following way to send it:

```
 const device = new Device(token, {
        logLevel: 0,
        codecPreferences: ['opus', 'pcmu']
      })
      device.register()
      async function makeOutgoingCall() {
        const params = {
          "MyCustomField": "my data",
          params:{To: psy.id}
        };
        const call = await device.connect(params);

        }...
```

Without good results.

Kevin A.